# PayFlow Pro Security Token Generation Error

Tags: rest, paypal, salesforce, payflowpro, payflowlink

I am using Rest API to get security token using unique securityID and other parameters. I am using following code :

```
HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
httpRequest.setEndpoint('https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com');
String body = 'PARTNER=Paypal&PWD=pwd&VENDOR=abc&USER=abc&CREATESECURERTOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=9a9ea8208de1413abc3d60c86cb1f4ce&TRXTYPE=C&AMT=23.0&MODE=TEST';
httpRequest.setBody(body);
httpRequest.setMethod('GET');
Http htt = new hTTP();
HttpResponse httpRe = htt.send(httpRequest);
system.debug(httpRe.geTbody());
```

But I am getting following error : RESULT=2&PNREF=A7X06D187FF7&RESPMSG=Invalid tender

Please suggest how to rectify this.

Comment: You are supposed to do a POST, not a GET

Answer (score 0):

You dont appear to be passing a tender type:

TENDER (Required) The method of payment. Values are:
* A = Automated clearinghouse
* C = Credit card
* D = Pinless debit
* K = Telecheck
* P = PayPal
See the Payflow ACH Payment Service Guide for details on the Automated
clearinghouse tender type.

Comment: Is this required for getting security token ?

Comment: You are getting the Invalid tender error because you are not passing the "Tender" NVP. According to the [Payflow Pro Developer's Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_payflowpro_guide.pdf), Page 26 it is a required parameter.

Comment: As per this video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyiv3ndRcZI. We only need to add amount and transaction type.I just need to get security token. I don't want to do transaction.

Comment: Like this is the example : curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -kd
"PARTNER=PayPal&
VENDOR=MyMerchantID&
USER=UserID&
PWD=UserPassword&
TRXTYPE=S&
AMT=40&
CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&
SECURETOKENID=12528208de1413abc3d60c86cb15"

Comment: @user3727204 Did you ever solve this? I'm experiencing the same problem.